# начальная настройка SQLite в дебиане

Tags: sqlite, debian

Установил SQLite (нужен SQLite3) через `Менеджер пакетов Synaptic`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверяю установку по инструкции с [сайта](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=2277) набирая команду:

```
root@localhost:/home/ia# sqlite3
bash: sqlite3: команда не найдена
root@localhost:/home/ia#
```

Что я сделал не так и как проверить работоспособность SQLite?

Comment: Не sqlyte3, а sqlite3

Comment: @andreymal это не будте работать, это lib для python

Comment: запустите Python и там попробуйте импортировать lib sqlite3: python  и import sqlite3

Comment: @users В питоне `import sqlite3` проходит без проблем.

Comment: @EmptyMan значит все работает, Django её как раз и использует

Comment: @EmptyMan единственное я бы не использовал не Synaptic, а pip для установки пакетов для Python

Comment: @users (на первом скриншоте) это не пакет Python, а системная библиотека, поставляющася с командой sqlite3, в которой была сделана опечатка

Comment: ...которую автор по-тихому поправил

Comment: @andreymal речь о Django, а они использует lib из Python, да и в скриншотах вроде как python-sqlite, а не sqlite

Comment: Здесь два скриншота, я как раз поправил свой коммент)

Comment: А вообще я так подозреваю, что не помешает доустановить пакет, который называется просто sqlite3

Comment: В общем sqlite3 не помешает, выполните команду `apt-get install sqlite3` и уже потом будет работать `sqlite3`, но для `Django` нужно установить  `lib` для `Python` командой  `pip install sqlite3`

Comment: @users чуть поправлю команду `sudo apt-get install sqlite3` и потом действительно заработало sqlite3. Спасибо всем!

Comment: Не много не понимаю при чем тут `Django`, просто специально проверил на тестовом сервере с `debian` и у меня `Django` работает с `SQLite` без `sqlite3`, и ставил только `python3-sqlite3`

Comment: @users Я использую `Django` и не знаю, нужно или нет его здесь указывать. Если уверены, что `Django` здесь не нужен, то, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: @EmptyMan, просто я все еще не понимаю в чем проблема, у вас не работает `sqlite3` в проекте `Django` или вам просто нужна программа  `sqlite3` для  `linux `?

Comment: @users у меня не работал `sqlite3` для `linux`, установил благодаря `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`. Как проверить работу `sqlite3` в `Django` еще не знаю, но хочется верить, что все работает.